# eliminating duplicated lists from a nested list c#

Tags: c#, nested-lists

i have a nested list that contains a set of lists, some of these lists are duplicated, i wanna just make a second list without duplicated lists. i tried this :

```
        List<List<string>> liste1 = new List<List<string>>();
        List<List<string>> liste2 = new List<List<string>>();
        List<string> l1 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
        List<string> l2 = new List<string> { "h", "x", "g" };
        List<string> l3 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
        List<string> l4 = new List<string> { "z", "t", "n" };
        liste1.Add(l1);
        liste1.Add(l2);
        liste1.Add(l3);
        liste1.Add(l4);
        foreach (List<string> lis in liste1)
        { 
             if(!liste2.Contains(lis))
             {
                liste2.Add(lis);
             }
        }
```

it seems easy but its not working, any help will be appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Linq`, you could achieve this.

You could take help of extension methods and look for `SequentialEqual` of two lists. If the order is not important use `Except` extension (something like ...`s.Except(x).Any()`).

```
var liste2= liste1.Where((x,i)=> !liste1.Skip(i+1).Any(s=>s.SequenceEqual(x)));
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xppdyE)

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for reference equality. Instead of using `Contains` try this substitution

```
//if (!liste2.Contains(lis))
if(!liste2.Any(subList => subList.SequenceEqual(lis)))
```

`SequenceEqual` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`. I think you will need a using statement importing the `System.Linq` namespace.

If you dont want to test that the child lists are not sequence-equal, but set-equal (i.e. order is not important), then consider using an implementation of `ISet<T>` like `HashSet<int>` instead of `List<int>`.